# http response coming back obfuscated

Tags: java, utf-8, response, decode, encode

I am making a call to a clients api, and it comes back like this

```
"user_firstname": "à¸à¸£à¸±à¸à¸à¸²à¸à¸´",
"user_lastname": "à¸¨à¸£à¸µà"
```

I have no idea what to do with this.
I have tried every kind of decoding I could think of

```
UTF-8 decoded
ดรัณชาติ

UTF-16 decoded to UTF-8
쎠슸슔쎠슸슣쎠슸슱쎠슸슓쎠슸슊쎠슸슲쎠슸슕쎠슸슴

UTF-32 decoded to UTF-8
쎠슸슔쎠슸슣쎠슸슱쎠슸슓쎠슸슊쎠슸슲쎠슸슕쎠슸슴

RAW URL decoded
à¸à¸£à¸±à¸à¸à¸²à¸à¸´

URL encode
%C3%A0%C2%B8%C2%94%C3%A0%C2%B8%C2%A3%C3%A0%C2%B8%C2%B1%C3%A0%C2%B8%C2%93%C3%A0%C2%B8%C2%8A%C3%A0%C2%B8%C2%B2%C3%A0%C2
```

Anyone have any Ideas on how to get at this data in a english readable from? Cause right now I am thinking it is Chinese.

finally just for kicks and giggles,

google translate says that this `쎠슸슔쎠슸슣쎠슸슱쎠슸슓쎠슸슊쎠슸슲쎠슸슕쎠슸슴` is korean for:

```
Ssyeoseut syursssyeo seutsyut ssyeoseut seurtssyeo seutsyurb ssyeoseut syukssyeo seutseurp ssyeoseut syurtssyeo seutseum
```

ok in Thai the utf8 is `ดรัณชาติ` which google translate says is "At the National Cathedral."

but I know for a fact that the user name which is what I have been trying to decode, is `William Davis`.

Comment: Are you sure it is English? The UTF8 string looks pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: had the same thought, posted a edit

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: The first String ("UTF-8 decoded") is translated to "At the National Cathedral." by Google. Seems fine.

Comment: At least, the Google translation for the UTF-8 decoded makes sense: are you sure that it's not intended?

Comment: Shouldnt be, the username should be my name, this is weird, i wonder if their server is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ดรัณชาติ is a Thai name.  Given that you're expecting a name in that field, I'd say that the UTF-8 is correct.

Comment: Except that is should be my name... and my name is not thai

Comment: Given that it is returning a name, albeit not the one you expect I'd say that there is either something strange with the request you're making or the logic on the server.